# WPF: Correct approach for UserControl inheritance/abstraction

Tags: c#, wpf

I implemented a file input mask as a user control that I want to re-use in my WPF application in two different contexts.

While the view (in the two cases) is actually pretty much the same, the ViewModel and the logic I implemented there is quite different.

I have already tried to inherit from a common AbstractFileInputView together with an abstract ViewModel, but that seems to break as soon as I put it in XAML.

Since I wasn't able to find some actual documentation about how to build re-usable (abstract) user controls, I am wondering if somebody has any hints on how to solve this?

Or do I really just have to go on a copy-and-paste spree here?

Comment: It's not clear from your question, but in case the UserControl has something like its own, private view model, that would be the wrong approach. A UserControl should instead expose a set of bindable properties, that you can then bind to two completely different view models.

Comment: Your question is too broad. That said, look to other built-in UI objects for guidance. They don't define a view model. They have dependency properties, which you bind source properties of your own view model to. That way the client code gets to decide the exact nature of the view model, and the UI elements are reusable without any coupling to the client code.

Comment: Can you clarify your file input mask?  Are you trying to offer something like a "..." button to pick a file or folder and a label to show what was picked?  And since similar in operation, but one file vs folder, having a flag to differentiate?  If you can edit your post and provide additional details would help.